домашний обиход meaning
This is from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924, and I find the writer has a convoluted manner of expression:

Большевицкое государство, заполнившее собой безгосударственную
пустоту, образовавшуюся послѣ революціи, совмѣстило въ себѣ начала,
столь противоположныя, что ужъ одно представленіе объ ихъ совмѣстности
подавляетъ наше сознаніе: жгучую остроту мученій съ мучительной
длительностью, безмѣрность разрушенія съ нестерпимой узостью домашняго
обихода

Multitran says домашний обиход means "household". обиход on its own means "custom, use". I can't get a good meaning from this phrase. Daily life???

The context can help. Firstly you can see the word противоположные, so there should be the complete antithesis. Then you see the examples.
безмѣрность разрушенія съ нестерпимой узостью домашняго обихода
The immensity of destruction with the narrowness of domestic life(with its traditions and customs).
